# What kind of layout and java class should i use for a friend list layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-activity

I am learning android development and i am kinda stuck here. I want to create a friend list screen like shown in this picture.

[image]

What kind of activity should i use? Is there any available resources similar to what i want to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) , also check out tutorials on lists, for example:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

you can find mire tutorials on google.

also you can use a regular [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class with [listView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) in the layout file

Answer (score 0):

1. Use list view and custom adapter to populate the list view...

Listview should extend to the bottom but limit it just above the `Type a name` edit text and button.

Custom list view should contain `linear layout horizontal` in that include `checkbox`, `Textview` and `Button`

1. For `type a name` and `Add` use linear layout horizontal

Comment: How can i store the friends added?

Comment: you need to use a `Sqlite database` to add friends and use custom cursor adapter to retrive and display in list view

Answer (score 0):

Use listView with custom adapter , for array use arrayList<,friends,> sure you have to create  friends class, in xml file put ListView then below that button and TextView